# Learning Handlebars: why isn't data being passed to my template if I don't use `this`

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm learning Handlebars and using this piece of code below after looking at a couple of tutorials. Below, my code won't work if I **don't** use the keyword `this`; I tried `{{#each shoesData}}` and nothing happens to my HTML. If I don't want to use `this`, it will work only if I change the shoesData to JS Example #2 (following an example from another tutorial that uses the name of an object and **not** `this` keyword) and also, in my template wrote `{{#each shoes}}`. What's the difference?

```
  <h3>The List of Shoes:</h3>
  <ul class="shoesNav"></ul>​

  <script id="shoe-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each this}}
      <li class="shoes"><a href="/{{name}}">{{name}} -- Price: {{price}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
  </script>
```

JavaScript #1

```
  var shoesNav = document.getElementsByClassName("shoesNav");
  var theTemplateScript = document.getElementById("shoe-template").innerHTML;
  var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);

  var shoesData =[
      {
        name: "Nike",
        price: 199.00
      },
      {
        name: "Loafers",
        price: 59.00
      },
      {
        name: "Wing Tip",
        price: 259.00
      }
    ];

  var theCompiledTemplate = theTemplate(shoesData);
  shoesNav[0].innerHTML = theCompiledTemplate;
```

JavaScript #2

```
  var shoesData =
  {
    shoes: [
      {
        name: "Nike",
        price: 199.00
      },
      {
        name: "Loafers",
        price: 59.00
      },
      {
        name: "Wing Tip",
        price: 259.00
      }
    ]
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item you are passing to your template is the array that is referenced by the variable 'shoesData'. So when the template sees it the 'this' object looks like this:

```
    [
      {
        name: "Nike",
        price: 199.00
      },
      {
        name: "Loafers",
        price: 59.00
      },
      {
        name: "Wing Tip",
        price: 259.00
      }
    ]
```

In Javascript #2, the object passed to the template is the value referenced by shoesData, which in this case is:

```
  {
    shoes: [
      {
        name: "Nike",
        price: 199.00
      },
      {
        name: "Loafers",
        price: 59.00
      },
      {
        name: "Wing Tip",
        price: 259.00
      }
    ]
  };
```

Do you see the difference? In the second example, the template sees an object with a property of `shoes`. In your example (Javascript #1) it simply sees an array.

The `this` parameter in both cases represents what is passed to the template so in your javascript it works with `this` because it represents an array that can be iterated over by the `{{#each ... }}`.

To fix this issue to work the way you expect, change the shoesData to look like this:

```
shoesData = {  
  shoes:
    [
      {
        name: "Nike",
        price: 199.00
      },
      {
        name: "Loafers",
        price: 59.00
      },
      {
        name: "Wing Tip",
        price: 259.00
      }
    ]
  }
```

Now you can use `{{#each shoes}}` in your template.

Another way to think of this, if you are still stuck, is what do you see if you do `console.log(shoesData)` in both examples? This will tell you what the handlebars will see as the `this` object, and if you do `console.log(shoesData.shoes)` in the second example, this is what will be iterated over when you do `{{#each shoes}}`.